# Oracle Table Column Summaries

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am trying to summarize some massive tables in a way that can help me investigate further for some data issues. There are hundreds of 1000s of rows, and roughly 80+ columns of data in most of these tables.

From each table, I have already performed queries to throw out any columns that have all nulls or 1 value only. I've done this for 2 reasons.... for my purposes, a single value or nulls in the columns are not interesting to me and provide little information about the data; additionally, the next step is that I want to query each of the remaining columns and return up to 30 distinct values in each column (if the column has more than 30 distinct values, we show the 1st 30 distinct values).

Here is the general format of output I wish to create:

```
Column_name(total_num_distinct): distinct_val1(val1_count), distinct_val2(val2_couunt), ... distinct_val30(val30_count)
```

Assuming my data fields are integers, floats, and varchar2 data types, this is the SQL I was trying to use to generate that output:

```
declare
begin
for rw in (
  select column_name colnm, num_distinct numd
  from all_tab_columns
  where
    owner = 'scz' 
    and table_name like 'tbl1' 
    and num_distinct > 1
  order by num_distinct desc
) loop
  dbms_output.put(rw.colnm || '(' || numd || '): ');
  for rw2 in (
    select dis_val, cnt from (
      select rw.colnm dis_val, count(*) cnt
      from tbl1
      group by rw.colnm
      order by 2 desc
    ) where rownum <= 30
  ) loop
     dbms_output.put(rw2.dis_val || '(' || rw2.cnt || '), ');
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(' ');
end loop;
end;
```

I get the output I expect from the 1st loop, but the 2nd loop that is supposed to output examples of the unique values in each column, coupled with the frequency of their occurrence for the 30 values with the highest frequency of occurrence, appears to not be working as I intended.  Instead  of seeing unique values along with the number of times that value occurs in the field, I get the column names and count of total records in that table.

If the 1st loop suggests the first 4 columns in 'tbl1' with more than 1 distinct value are the following:

```
| colnm | numd   |
|----------------|
| Col1  | 2      |
| Col3  | 4     |
| Col7  | 17     |
| Col12 | 30     |
```

... then the full output of 1st and 2nd loop together looks something like the following from my SQL:

```
Col1(2): Col1(tbl1_tot_rec_count), Col3(tbl1_tot_rec_count)
Col3(4): Col1(tbl1_tot_rec_count), Col3(tbl1_tot_rec_count), Col7(tbl1_tot_rec_count), Col12(tbl1_tot_rec_count)
Col7(17): Col1(tbl1_tot_rec_count), Col3(tbl1_tot_rec_count), Col7(tbl1_tot_rec_count), Col12(tbl1_tot_rec_count), .... , ColX(tbl1_tot_rec_count)
Col12(30): Col1(tbl1_tot_rec_count), Col3(tbl1_tot_rec_count), Col7(tbl1_tot_rec_count), Col12(tbl1_tot_rec_count), .... , ColX(tbl1_tot_rec_count)
```

The output looks cleaner when real data is output, each table outputting somewhere between 20-50 lines of output (i.e. columns with more than 2 values), and listing 30 unique values for each field (with their counts) only requires a little bit of scrolling, but isn't impractical. Just to give you an idea with fake values, the output would look more like this with real data if it was working correctly (but fake in my example):

```
Col1(2): DisVal1(874,283), DisVal2(34,578), 
Col3(4): DisVal1(534,223), DisVal2(74,283), DisVal3(13,923), null(2348)
Col7(17): DisVal1(54,223), DisVal2(14,633), DisVal3(13,083), DisVal4(12,534), DisVal5(9,876), DisVal6(8,765), DisVal7(7654), DisVal8(6543), DisVal9(5432), ...., ...., ...., ...., ...., ...., ...., DisVal17(431)
```

I am not an Oracle or SQL guru, so I might not be approaching this problem in the easiest, most efficient way. While I do appreciate any better ways to approach this problem, I also want to learn why the SQL code above is not giving me the output I expect. My goal is trying to quickly run a single query that can tell me which columns have interesting data I might what to examine further in that table. I have probably 20 tables I need to examine that are all of similar dimensions and so very difficult to examine comprehensively. Being able to reduce these tables in this way to know what possible combinations of values may exist across the various fields in each of these tables would be very helpful in further queries to deep dive into the intricacies of the data.

Comment: you can't use coumn values directly as column nmes, you need dynamic sql see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `select rw.colnm dis_val, count(*) cnt from tbl1 group by rw.colnm order by 2 desc` is not doing at all what you think, and what you think to be done can't be done without dynamic SQL. What it does is in fact `select 'a_column_of_tabl1' dis_val, count(*) cnt from tbl1 group by 'a_column_of_tabl1'  order by 2 desc` and what you need to do is execute dynamically the SQL: '`select ' || rw.colnm || ' dis_val, count(*) cnt from tbl1 group by ' || rw.colnm || ' order by 2 desc'`.

Comment: So you're saying that I need to use something like cursors in a PL/SQL-like structure to dynamically construct the SQL query in a string variable and then execute it?  I've played with more advanced SQL like this, but it's been very difficult for me to write such code and debug. I'm more of an engineer and not an expert with SQL and I use it secondarily to dissect or query data but it's not my specialty so I struggle with it at times.

Comment: Yes, it's not an easy task for a beginner but you can start by generating the SQL for 1 column and output it in DBMS_OUTPUT and then execute it manually. Once you have the solution it will be easier to put it in a loop.

Comment: Also you should not process columns having either a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on them or being the unique column of an UNIQUE INDEX, the count() on the these will always be 1....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the (beta) query you can use to get the SQL to execute:
(I tested with user_* VIEWs instead of ALL_* to avoid getting to many results here...)

```
select utc.table_name, utc.column_name,
    REPLACE( REPLACE(q'~select col_name, col_value, col_counter
from (
    SELECT col_name, col_value, col_counter, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col_counter DESC) AS rn
    FROM (
        select '{col_name}' AS col_name, 
            {col_name} AS col_value, COUNT(*) as col_counter    
        from {table_name} 
        group by {col_name}
    )
)
WHERE rn <= 30~', '{col_name}', utc.column_name), '{table_name}', utc.table_name)  AS sql
from user_tab_columns utc 
where not exists( 
    select 1
    from user_indexes ui
    join user_ind_columns uic on uic.table_name = ui.table_name 
        and uic.index_name = ui.index_name
    where 
        ui.table_name = utc.table_name
    and exists ( 
        select 1 from user_ind_columns t where t.table_name = ui.table_name 
            and t.index_name = uic.index_name and t.column_name = utc.column_name
    )
    group by ui.table_name, ui.index_name having( count(*) = 1 )
)
and not exists( 
    SELECT 1
    FROM user_constraints uc
    JOIN user_cons_columns ucc ON ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
    WHERE constraint_type IN (
        'P', -- primary key 
        'U' -- unique 
    )
    AND uc.table_name = utc.table_name AND ucc.column_name = utc.column_name
)
;
```